# Solution verification: family of polynomials, $\gcd$ of polynomials

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, solution-verification

> Let $P$ be a family of polynomials $\mathcal P:=\{p_n(x):n\in\mathbb
>  N\}$ $$p_n(x)=x^3+2(1-n)x^2+n(n-4)x+2n^2$$ Let $f(x)\in\mathbb R[x]$
>   s.t. $\;\gcd(p_n(x),f(x))=d(x),\;\forall n\in\mathbb N.$
>
> $(a)$ Are there any $f(x)\;\&\;d(x),\;\deg(d(x))=1$?
>
> $(b)$ Are there any $f(x)\;\&\;d(x)$ s.t. $d(x)$ has a multiple root?

My attempt:

By the theorem:

> If $\alpha=\frac{p}{q}\in\mathbb Q$ is a root of the equation:
>   $$a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\ldots+a_{n-1}x+a_n=0,\;a_i\in\mathbb Z\;\forall
> i\in\{0,1,\ldots,n\},\;\gcd(p,q)=1$$ then $p|a_n\;\land\;q|a_0.$

Since the statements must hold $\forall n\in\mathbb N$, let $\alpha=\pm\frac{2}{1}$

Case $ii:$ For $\alpha=-2$, by long division:

$$\frac{x^3+2(1-n)x^2+n(n-4)x+2n^2}{x+2}=(x-n)^2$$

$$\implies p_n(x)=(x+2)(x-n)^2\implies x_1=-2,x_{2,3}=n$$

$(a)$ $\deg(d(x))=1\implies d(x)=x+2$

$$\implies f(x)=(x+2)q(x),\;\gcd(q(x),(x-n)^2)=1\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$$

$(b)$ If $d(x)$ has multiple roots $\alpha$, then must $\alpha=-2$
$$\implies f(x)=(x+2)^kq(x),\;\gcd(q(x),(x-n)^2)=1$$

Case $ii:\;\alpha=2$ isn't a root of the given equation.

My answer to both $(a)\;\&\;(b)$ is yes.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $p_n(x)=(x-n)^2(x+2)$ the answer to (a) is yes because you can take $f(x)=x+2$.

Your answer of $d(x)=x-2$ does not work since this is not a factor of, say,  $p_1(x)$.

For (b) the answer is also yes because if $f(x)=(x+2)^3$, then $d(x)=x+2$ and $f(x)=(x+2)^2 d(x)$.

[I hope this is what you are intending.]

Comment: thank you for noticing, that was a typo I copied a few times after. $q(x)\in\mathbb R[x]$, I should've written that in the first place. Thank you for responding!

Comment: Thanks, I have amended my answer.